# Added space to LVM, shows up in Size, but as Used

Tags: centos, rhel, lvm, mdadm, xfs

My root partition is XFS on LVM.

Before I did anything, I had two physical disks which were combined using md as `/dev/md126` into a PV. That PV was the only member of a VG `centos_x5backup`, and there were two LVs, `root` and `swap`.

I was running out of disk space:

```
# df -h /
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_x5backup-root  590G  509G   81G  86% /
```

I wanted more space on `root`. I purchased two new drives, created a md `/dev/md0` combining them in raid1. That's active and resyncing:

```
md127 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdd1[1]
      999424 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[0] sdc1[1]
      1171979840 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      [=============>.......]  resync = 66.0% (773868928/1171979840) finish=393.1min speed=16874K/sec
      bitmap: 6/9 pages [24KB], 65536KB chunk
```

I added `md0` as a new PV in the existing VG, and resized:

```
ssm resize -s+100%FREE /dev/mapper/centos_x5backup-root
```

I've run `xfs-growfs -d /`:

```
# xfs_growfs -d /
meta-data=/dev/mapper/centos_x5backup-root isize=512    agcount=13, agsize=36031232 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=437118976, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=70373, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data size unchanged, skipping
```

But after all that:

```
# df -h /
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_x5backup-root  1.7T  1.6T   71G  96% /
```

What gives? df sees the space, but thinks its "used".

Why isn't the new space free?

Comment: Lots of useful output https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dmd/ec9f03717e946476dfea58c7203cf05a/raw/f786e096006af689d195a5257cf6c018383e9d78/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Can you show some information on `pvs;vgs;lvs`  or `lvmdiskscan`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Booting from a rescue disk and running `xfs_repair` on `/dev/mapper/centos_x5backup-root` fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution